# Hibernate - getResultList() returns multipled first row. Spring

Tags: hibernate

This is my session

```
    String query = "from Authority";
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<Authority> authorities= session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    session.close();

    for(Authority a: authorities){
        System.out.println(a.getEmail());
    }
```

This is my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Email
    @Column
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

This is my Authority class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authority {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String authority;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "email")
    private User user;
```

As I want to display my results I get a first row in every 'for' iteration.
Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Let's say that in my database are rows like:

```
email1@server.com  ROLE_USER
email2@server.com  ROLE_USER
email3@server.com  ROLE_USER
email4@server.com  ROLE_USER
```

As a result of this "for" is:

```
email1@server.com
email1@server.com
email1@server.com
email1@server.com
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in the mapping.

The first problem is that `authority` column in `authorities` table is not a primary key. It is incorrect to mark it with `Id` annotation and this confuses hibernate.

The second (and the main) problem is that according to you model each user may have several authorities but your data suggests that each `Authority` may be related to many users. It seems that `authorities` table models many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Authority` entities while the mapping tries to fit it into one-to-many relationship.